# TeamCity - Use environment variable in buildAgent.properties file?

Tags: azure, teamcity, build-agent

I'm in the process of setting up TeamCity on Azure, more specifically I'm setting up some build agents.  Certain properties of the build agents are configured via the buildAgent.properties file like name, port etc.  I would like to call the agent the name of the computer it is located on but I can't find (and indeed don't know if this is possible) anyway to use environment variables to set the agent name i.e env.COMPUTERNAME?

The only way i seem to be able to do this is by hard coding the name

```
#Generated properties (see buildAgent.dist.properties for description)
name=tc-agent-001 #is it possible to use environment variable here?
ownPort=9090
serverUrl=http\://mybuildserver.mycompany.com
workDir=C\:\\BuildAgent\\work
tempDir=C\:\\BuildAgent\\temp
#User defined properties
env.TEAMCITY_JRE=C\:\\BuildAgent\\jre
```

Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Our agents had this behaviour by default.  It is the name property that appears in the env.COMPUTERNAME environment variable, and this was the hostname of each VM.

If your machine hostname is different to the listed name, just change that parameter, but as this file is just a parsed list of settings, there's not a way to have it programatically detect the hostname for you. - unless you write a script to detect the hostname of a machine and then modify the properties file.

Comment: I should also mention that we installed all of our agents using the windows installer rather than the 'Agent Push' feature - and the default environment vars are configurable from there.

Comment: Yes I thought I would have to modify this file when the agent started up to get the dynamic name in there.  Lets hope TeamCity sort out dynamically provisioning build agent in azure soon!

Comment: You can modify the file at any time, the agent will detect changes and restart itself.  So, if you wanted to go down the route of writing something to update the properties files of your agents, this would work fine.